# Multi column index search Microsoft.Isam.Esent

Tags: c#, esent

I am facing the following issue: I have an composite index on a database index1 {binaryColumn1, binaryColumn2}. I am using the following to set the index to use:

```
Api.JetSetCurrentIndex(_session, _table, index1);
```

to create the key:

```
Api.MakeKey(_session, _table, binaryValue, MakeKeyGrbit.NewKey);
```

and than try to perform the search with:

```
Api.TrySeek(_session, _table, SeekGrbit.SeekEQ);
```

This works and seek returns true correctly if index1 is only for 1 column. If I have multiple columns and try to search the value for a single column (ex. for binaryColumn1 = {0x01, 0x23}) it always returns false.

How can I search for this one value? (ps. I cannot change the index nor create new ones.) Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did would only work for `{0x01, 0x00}`. You can't do it with a single call, because the value of the second column will be mixing up the `SeekEQ` grbit.

You could do a `SeekGE`, but then you'll need to retrieve the column to make sure the value is actually correct (and not something like `{0x22, 0x23}`). You'll have to do something like:

`SetCurrentIndex()
MakeKey( ..., binaryValue1, MakeKeyGrbit.NewKey | MakeKeyGrbit.FullColumnStartLimit); // Appends the rest of the search buffer with 0x00's.
Seek(GE);
MakeKey(... binaryValue1, MakeKeyGrbit.NewKey | MakeKeyGrbit.FullColumnEndLimit); // Appends the rest of the search buffer with 0xff's.
Api.JetSetIndexRange();`

Then you can use `Api.TryMoveNext()` to iterate through all rows that have that column equal to `binaryValue1`.

Also look at the test code included with the project -- the `HowDoI.cs` file has lots of good examples.

Sorry for the pseudo-code; I don't have the source code handy at the moment.

-martin